# generating a bash script

Tags: perl, bash

How do I use Perl to create another file known as `hello.sh`?

I tried:

```
#*perl codes*
#Before this has perl's section of codes
#Now want to create shell script
open FILE , ">hello.sh" or die $!;
chmod 0755, "hello.sh";
print FILE
"#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World!
";
close FILE;
```

But this is pretty redundant. It would be very hard to do this if I want to use IF-ELSE.

Any idea?

EDIT

I tried this

```
print FILE
"#!/bin/sh
if [-d $1]; then
echo "It's a directory at $(pwd)"
else
echo $1 is not a directory
fi
";
```

As you can see, the `Its` detects as not a string,
Did I miss any syntax here?

Comment: Perl can print anything to a file that you could type into a file, yes.

Comment: Yes you can, no there's nothing difficult to it, and your comment makes no sense at all.

Comment: You're not printing your file's contents. It's just a string, not going anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should print content to file handle `FILE`

```
open FILE , ">", "hello.sh" or die $!;
chmod 0755, "hello.sh";

print FILE <<'END';
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World!"
END

close FILE;
```

`<<'END' ..` is heredoc syntax which doesn't try to interpolate strings which perl would recognize as variables (prefixed with `$` or `@`)

It also ensures that `'` or `"` quotation marks don't need to be escaped with `\`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for, will google and study about it soon. But is that `q` could be anything?

Comment: yes, as long it isn't in content. I've renamed it to `END`

Comment: @mpapec It's worth noting that `unquoted(<<END)` or `double-quoted(<<"END"` will interpolate.

Comment: check @gpojd solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotation marks:

```
print FILE '#!/bin/sh
if [-d $1]; then
echo "It\'s a directory at $(pwd)"
else
echo $1 is not a directory
fi
';
```

Or use [q](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/q.html):

```
print FILE q{#!/bin/sh
if [-d $1]; then
echo "It's a directory at $(pwd)"
else
echo $1 is not a directory
fi
};
```

Or a heredoc:

```
print FILE <<'OUT';
#!/bin/sh
if [-d $1]; then
echo "It's a directory at $(pwd)"
else
echo $1 is not a directory
fi
OUT
```

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value $1 in string` … also, `$(` is the real group ID of the process. Use a non-interpolating quote delimiter (`'...'`, `q{}`, `<<'OUT'`). Note: `$1` is the first argument in shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
open FILE , ">hello.sh" or die $!;
chmod 0755, "hello.sh";
print FILE "#!/bin/sh
echo Hello World!
";
close FILE;
```